# What are the pre-requisite for creating Azure DevOps organization

Tags: azure-devops

I have been struggling to find a guidance or best practice documentation for new Azure Tenant who want to start the Azure DevOps Service journey.

The Azure DevOps documentation is created in a piece meal approach and there is no proper documentation about such guidance and it is maddening to scan through several Azure DevOps product/feature to figure out the content I wanted.

From the documentation, I understand that one needs to create Azure Organization and project structure etc. and then users within the AAD (Company's MAC tenant) can be added to Organization or at project level to collaborate.

But if I am a new Organization or Entity that has just acquired a Azure Commercial Cloud subscription then what are the guidelines to setup my Azure DevOps organization?

> E.g. Do I have to be a Global Admin of my Azure Commercial
>   Subscription to first start the Azure DevOps Organization? Or can I be
>   a Admin for Dev/Test Subscription and then start the Azure DevOps
>   Organization? Can I use my Dev/test subscription to create Azure
>   DevOps organization? What are some limitation or restruction with regard to my Azure Subscription in terms of ability to create Azure DevOps organization? What roles are advised to initiate the Organization creation process?

Where is the guidance documentation or best practice documentation around it so we can put a proper governance structure on Azure DevOps - organization/project and users etc.

Comment: I figured it out. Basically anyone with Admin privileges (e.g, Account Admin) can first create an Organization for the company and then can add other users with different role in that org. You will add new users with Project or Build admin in the Azure DevOps org and then they can create new Projects in the organization and invite/add other developers/testers/stakeholder in the projects.   When you sign-in using your work account  it automatically connect to AAD when first time you go to https://dev.azure.com to signup.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some high level prerequisite for setting up Azure DevOps Service:

- You must have a tenant in Azure Commercial or Public Cloud. You can still deploy and build on other cloud or on-premise. You need public cloud to host your DevOps Org and project configuration and optionally to host the git based code repo.
- You need a Subscription in Azure Public cloud tenant
- You will need a user with Account Admin, Service Admin or Subscription Admin level privileges to create first DevOPs Organization
- After creating the DevOps Organization, Users (scrum master, Managers, developers and testers ) can be invited to these organization from DevOps Organization settings
- Users who have Visual Studio (VS) Enterprise licenses will see most of the features in the Azure DevOps Service Organization. So having a Visual Studio Enterprise or professional license subscription is useful and these users are counted as free for Azure DevOps service user pool. These VS license already come with benefit attached and part of those benefit is the access to Azure DevOps service.
- It will be greatly beneficial for Admin team (devOps Org management team) to try to understand how Azure DevOps Service Access levels and permission works and how they are mapped to different Visual Studio licenses and how to configure these access for different role of users. You can find useful information in this regard on AzureDocs.
- You do not need to have Visual Studio license (it is optional) to use Azure DevOps Service. By default Azure DevOps service is free for small team of 5 developers with limited access to features. So small organization can immediately start using it within their Enterprise Account or Pay-as-you-go subscription. You can add users to your Azure DevOps Service organization irrespective of if they have VS licenses and you can pay for their subscription on a monthly basis.

Also, I will highly recommend training course from [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/) website on Azure DevOps Service to get excellent understanding of prerequisite and features of Azure DevOps Service. Just search for DevOps keyword and you will find number of courses with different modules that will provide step by step instructions on setting up your first Azure DevOps Service Organization to integrating with GitHub and building pipeline, static code analysis etc.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, as the answer becomes useless if the link ever changes.

Comment: @DanielMann Appreciate the feedback. Fixed those links. I do not think that Microsoft learn top level domain for Microsoft Learn website will change in the future.